# Compare adjacent variable in list and reformat the input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
inp = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 20, 25,27,28,29,31]
```

The expected output: If the adjacent variable is in series, fill with a hyphen. If not, append the given number.

```
Expected Output = [1-3,5,7-12,14,17,20,25,27-29,31]
```

I have taken an adjacent number using the below code. But the requirements are not satisfied.

```
inp = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 20, 25,27,28,29,31]
for x,y in zip(inp[::],inp[1::]):
    print(x,y)
```

Comment: input is a keyword, never use it to name a variable. Also the output lis will contain items or string type

Comment: yes..noted. thanks. kindly help to solve this puzzle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple task if you use the [`consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups) function from [`more-itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/). This uses [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) under the hood, similar to [@Andrej Kesely's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61850708/compare-adjacent-variable-in-list-and-reformat-the-input/61850770#61850770) answer. If you want to look at the source code to see how this is implemented, here is the function on [GitHub](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.py#L2259).

```
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups

inp = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 20, 25, 27, 28, 29, 31]

result = [
    f"{group[0]}-{group[-1]}" if len(group) > 1 else f"{group[0]}"
    for group in map(list, consecutive_groups(inp))
]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['1-3', '5', '7-12', '14', '17', '20', '25', '27-29', '31']
```

Comment: Wow!!!. That was awesome. Thanks a lot. I will check the documentation to know more. Thanks for your reference.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 20, 25,27,28,29,31]

out = []
for _, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda k: k[1]-k[0]):
    g = [*g]
    if len(g) == 1:
        out.append(str(g[0][1]))
    else:
        out.append('{}-{}'.format(g[0][1], g[-1][1]))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['1-3', '5', '7-12', '14', '17', '20', '25', '27-29', '31']
```